# How to increment date object hours with omitting weekend days

Tags: javascript, date, javascript-objects

I'm making a deadline calculator function in JavaScript using Date object.

I have a date and a turnaround time for inputs, and the algorithm gives back the deadline in a date. It works now fine, however when I increment the date object with a turnaround time big enough to start a new week, it includes the weekend days as well. This crushes my whole algorithm, because I don't want to count the weekends as valid working hours.

Can I somehow make a setting on the Date object, to omit weekend days? For example:

```
0 = "Sunday";
1 = "Monday";
2 = "Tuesday";
3 = "Wednesday";
4 = "Thursday";
5 = "Friday";
6 = "Saturday";

Thursday date + 24 hours => Friday date. But Friday date + 72 hours => Monday date
instead of Wednesday date.
```

How could I calculate the deadline without using the weekend days, so when I give 72 hour to a Friday date for example, I would not get Monday, but Wednesday instead? Like if the Date object would jump weekend days over.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude weekends between two dates using Moment.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788411/how-to-exclude-weekends-between-two-dates-using-moment-js)

Comment: @Julian Yeah, I'm not using Moment.js

Comment: Good point, although it is recommend to use Moment.js

Comment: I think it would be hard to do this without Moment.js, and why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Okay, I'm going to dig into it. However my algorithm is already implemented, using Date object. I figured, maybe converting the turnaround hours into (days + hours), and first incrementing the days may give a chance to skip the weekends.

Comment: It's not hard at all without a library, see [*Add Working Days Using Javascript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739059/add-working-days-using-javascript) ([*and many others*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+working+days)). You really should post what you've tried.

Comment: @Julian recommended by who? Yes, I recommend it but you didn't ask me.

Comment: Btw I absolutely do not get the downvote's reason. This is a valid question, and far from trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, trying to follow Clean Code conception, I've put the whole algorithm into separete functions. I'm ommiting a couple of other functions, the main part is covered by the following:

```
function incrementWithTime(submit, days, hours_to_increment) {
    let date = new Date(submit);
    repeatThis(days) (() => date = pushToNextWeekIfReachedWeekend(new Date(date.getTime() + (24*1000*3600))));
    date = new Date(date.getTime() + (hours_to_increment*1000*3600));
    return date;
}
```

This increments the Date object day-by-day. Why do we need this? Well, I had to know where the time interval reaches a weekend day, so I can 'step' on it, and skip, using the **pushToNextWeekIfReachedWeekend()** method:

```
function pushToNextWeekIfReachedWeekend(submit) {
    let date = new Date(submit);
    let day = date.getDay();
    const saturday = 6, sunday = 0;

if(day == saturday)
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2);    
if(day == sunday)
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
return date;
}
```

Now, if you wonder how the **reapeatThis()** works:

```
const repeatThis = x => f => {
    if (x > 0) {
        f();
        repeatThis(x - 1)(f);
    }
}
```