# Add future days to Javascript excluding on sunday

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript code that allows a user to only select four days in future from today's date.

```js
$(function() {
  var dtToday = new Date();

  var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
  if (dtToday.getDay() === 0) {
    var day = dtToday.getDate() + 5;
  } else {
    var day = dtToday.getDate() + 4;
  }
  var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
  if (month < 10)
    month = '0' + month.toString();
  if (day < 10)
    day = '0' + day.toString();

  var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
  $('.datepicker').attr('max', maxDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I would like the code to skip Sunday while incrementing the future days by four. I have tried using if statements but they only check if today's date is sunday while i would like to achieve a situation whereby if any of the future 4 days is Sunday, it should skip it.
Thanks

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40739059/4636715) discusses a similar case (including Saturdays also while incrementing), maybe you can have a look.

Comment: ok thanks
let me have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If today is Wednesday (3), Thursday (4), Friday (5), or Saturday (6), then your 4-day window would include Sunday (hence you should add 1 to days).
So do this:

```
var day = dtToday.getDate() + 4;
if(dtToday.getDay() > 2) {
    day += 1;
}
```

So your script would be:

```
$(function(){
        var dtToday = new Date();

        var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = dtToday.getDate() + 4;
        if(dtToday.getDay() > 2) {
            day += 1;
        }
        var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
        if(month < 10)
            month = '0' + month.toString();
        if(day < 10)
            day = '0' + day.toString();

        var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
        $('.datepicker').attr('max', maxDate);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Kindly accept my edit for a more specific way of how I solved the challenge.